# java.lang.IllegalStateException when creating a ScoreManager on Spring for OptaPlanner

Tags: spring, spring-boot, optaplanner

I got the following exception when trying to create a scoreManager :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The solutionClass (class my.package.MySolution) has been specified as a solution in the configuration, but does not have a @PlanningSolution annotation.

However, the MySolution class does have the @PlanningSolution annotation, and the xml config file used looks like this :

```
<solver>
   ...
  <solutionClass>my.package.MySolution</solutionClass>
  <entityClass>my.package.MyAssignment</entityClass>
   ...
</solver>
```

But when calling the SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource like this :

```
        SolverFactory<MySolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("solver/myRosteringSolverConfig.xml");

        var scoreManager = ScoreManager.create(solverFactory);
```

I got the mentioned exception. Which does not make sense, because 1) the config use the same solutionClass as used by the SolverFactory and 2) the class is annotated...

Comment: Can you share the `MySolution.java` source code of the solution class? It's very weird if that indeed is annotated correctly. I 've never seen that before.

Comment: Also, if you're using Quarkus or Spring, are you using the optaplanner-quarkus or optaplanner-spring-boot-starter? Any other fancy class loading things happening in your environment?

Comment: "optaplanner-spring-boot-starter" That might be the reason, I'm migrating Optaplanner, used to work (loading properly), but I guess I overlooked that. I'll try this and report back. Thanks for this suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class cast exception is probably because it's loading the same `@Planningsolution` class from two different jars.

Use `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter` to avoid such classloading issues.

Comment: Indeed, they are loading from two different JAR (is this a regression / change of strategy ? In 7.X that was not an issue). However now I'm getting the exception org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'solverManager' . I don't think I've missed anyhting from the migration regarding the configuration of the solverManager.

Comment: Try running this optaplanner spring quickstart code: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/technology/java-spring-boot
Then compare your code with it. Or create a *new* SO question with your full stacktrace.

Comment: I thought the issue was fixed, but after some changes, i still get the same exception when Spring tries to create the solverManager bean. (inner exception is the same). Btw, there are two modules in the project, a module containing everything related to optaplanner, the other one is the rest app. I've compared the two, however there are several differences (a .drl is used on our project is probably the most important one)