# Optaplanner - spring BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring-boot, optaplanner

I'm migrating Optaplanner from v7.x to v8.14 on a project that uses spring-boot (as a web api).

I've added the optaplanner-spring-boot-starter dependency to the project, however when starting the application, I got the following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solverManager' defined in class path resource [org/optaplanner/spring/boot/autoconfigure/OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The solutionClass (class be.my.domain.MySolution) has been specified as a solution in the configuration, but does not have a @PlanningSolution annotation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at be.my.WebgardesApplication.main(WebgardesApplication.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The solutionClass (class be.my.domain.MySolution) has been specified as a solution in the configuration, but does not have a @PlanningSolution annotation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The solutionClass (class be.my.domain.MySolution) has been specified as a solution in the configuration, but does not have a @PlanningSolution annotation.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.processSolutionAnnotations(SolutionDescriptor.java:269)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.processAnnotations(SolutionDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.buildSolutionDescriptor(SolutionDescriptor.java:120)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildSolutionDescriptor(DefaultSolverFactory.java:160)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildScoreDirectorFactory(DefaultSolverFactory.java:133)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildSolver(DefaultSolverFactory.java:87)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverManager.validateSolverFactory(DefaultSolverManager.java:69)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverManager.<init>(DefaultSolverManager.java:58)
    at org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager.create(SolverManager.java:111)
    at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.solverManager(OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration.java:98)
    at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8803e22a.CGLIB$solverManager$2(<generated>)
    at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8803e22a$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$40c364cf.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure.OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8803e22a.solverManager(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 25 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.optaplanner.core.api.solver.SolverManager]: Factory method 'solverManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The solutionClass (class be.my.domain.MySolution) has been specified as a solution in the configuration, but does not have a @PlanningSolution annotation.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The solutionClass (class be.my.domain.MySolution) has been specified as a solution in the configuration, but does not have a @PlanningSolution annotation.
```

The project is in two separated modules, one with everything related to Optaplanner (the config.xml, the .drl, the Solution, etc), the other is the spring-boot web api.

Here are the dependencies (.gradle) for both :

module "my-roster"

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-web:5.1.6.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.0.10.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.1.4.RELEASE'
    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre'
    implementation "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.0.Final"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.0.Final"

    implementation "org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:${optaplannerVersion}"
    implementation "org.optaplanner:optaplanner-persistence-xstream:${optaplannerVersion}"
    implementation "org.optaplanner:optaplanner-spring-boot-starter:${optaplannerVersion}"

    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner:2.11.0'
    implementation "org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.24.0-RC.0"
    implementation "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:5.2"
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.1.4.RELEASE'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.0.Final"

    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12'
    implementation 'org.json:org.json:chargebee-1.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
}
```

module "web-app"

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.0.Final"
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-afterburner'
    implementation "org.zalando:problem-spring-web:0.24.0-RC.0"
    implementation "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:5.2"
    implementation "org.optaplanner:optaplanner-core:${optaplannerVersion}"
    implementation "org.optaplanner:optaplanner-persistence-xstream:${optaplannerVersion}"
    implementation "org.optaplanner:optaplanner-spring-boot-starter:${optaplannerVersion}"
    implementation project(':my-roster')
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.7'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.9.7'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12'
    implementation 'org.json:org.json:chargebee-1.0'
}
```

the SolverConfig file :

```
<solver xmlns="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/solver" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/solver https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/solver/solver.xsd">


    <solutionClass>be.my.domain.MySolution</solutionClass>
    <entityClass>be.my.domain.DutyAssignment</entityClass>

...

</solver>
```

And the MySolution file :

```
package be.my.domain;

// Imports ...

@PlanningSolution
@XStreamAlias("MySolution")
public class MySolution extends AbstractPersistable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String code;

    //All the @ProblemFactProperty / CollectionProperty and the ProblemEntityCollectionProperty

    @PlanningScore
    private HardMediumSoftScore score;

    public MySolution(){}

//A lot of getters

}
```

EDIT : The @PlanningSolution class and the configuration files are in one module, the solverConfig, solverFactory, scoreManager, etc. are all built in the other package, could this be an issue in v8+ ?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70214881/java-lang-illegalstateexception-when-creating-a-scoremanager-on-spring-for-optap.

Comment: Almost the same. I opened both btw.

Comment: This question is clearer, thanks.

Comment: That EDIT might be right. That could be the cause because we have no integration tests that use a domain from another module. @Cromm can you confirm that if you put them all in the same module, the issue goes away? If that's true, then this is a genuine bug and we need to create a jira to track it.

Comment: I'll try this out, in the mean time I've noticed that at runtime, the MySolution.class, when set in the SolverConfig does not have any annotationData which is odd. I'll report back after putting everything in one module.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet : That's indeed the issue, by moving everything under the same module, that exception does not occur anymore. Do you need me to create a Jira ticket ? Where can I do it ?
NOTE : this was not an issue when we use the v7 of Optaplanner.

Comment: This is a clear regression. Thank you for reporting. Please create a ticket here: https://issues.redhat.com/projects/PLANNER/summary A reproducer is welcome but optional :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Optaplanner, the current workaround is to move the needed code from the different modules into one. Not ideal, but it works. To follow the issue : https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2600 Once resolved, this bug should not happen anymore.